# How do I limit the total columns and rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How do I limit the total column to 10 columna and total rows to 500 data per table in Mysql

Comment: 'limit the total column to 10 columna' - once db is designed restrict user priveleges, total rows to 500 data - uae triggers to reject >500?

Comment: Pls read [How much research effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/18254155)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like P.Salmon suggested,we can restrict users from altering table structures. This can be done by revoking their ALTER privilege on said tables. e.g `revoke alter on testdb.thistable from thisuser;` As to limit the total rows , we can use a trigger to check the existing row number every time a new row is to be inserted. If the limit is reached, abort the INSERT as well as raise a warning. The trigger looks like this:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists check_row_limit ;
create trigger check_row_limit before insert on thistable for each row 
begin
if  (select count(*) from thistable) >= 500 then
signal SQLSTATE VALUE '99999' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The number of rows has reached the limit. INSERT fails. ';
end if;

end//

delimiter ;
```